# loop in mysql i count if

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the 2 tables of name pooling_station and wind_turbine and in wind_turbine turbine_name is present.
I want to fetch the data of all turbine which consist of several turbine_id like SWSMHD-SC1-RWE01-G100 to SWSMHD-SC1-RWE01-G112

For that i am using this query

```
select turbine name,
       count(if(turbine_name = 'SWSMHD-SC1-RWE01-G112', 1, NULL)) as turbine_count,
from scada_data 
where
   local_tm BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-01' 
   and turbine_name in 
   (
      SELECT
         uniqueid 
      FROM
         wind_turbine 
      WHERE
         pooling_station = 20 
   );
```

but in this i have to enter the turbine_name for each turbine.

how can i get the all 12 turbine data in single query?

Comment: can you show what is being returned at the moment?

Comment: by this i am getting the only the count of SWSMHD-SC1-RWE01-G112 count equal to 144

Comment: dear, i have 20 pooling station and each pooling station consist of 12 turbine i have to fetch the data of all the turbine without giving the turbine_id again and again.

Comment: why turbine_name is checked in unique id ??                                       
 and turbine_name in 
   (
      SELECT
         uniqueid 
      FROM
         wind_turbine 
      WHERE
         pooling_station = 20 
   );

Comment: because uniqueid is the name of turbine which is in wind_turbine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `in` and `group by`:

```
select turbine_name, count(*) as turbine_count,
from scada_data 
where turbine_name in ('SWSMHD-SC1-RWE01-G112', . . . )
      local_tm BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-01' and
      turbine_name in (select uniqueid from wind_turbine where pooling_station = 20 )
group by turbine_name;
```

The `. . .` is for your list of `turbine_name`s.

If you want all matching turbines, just leave out the `in` condition:

```
select turbine_name, count(*) as turbine_count,
from scada_data 
where local_tm BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-01' and
      turbine_name in (select uniqueid from wind_turbine where pooling_station = 20 )
group by turbine_name;
```

Comment: where turbine_name in ('SWSMHD-SC1-RWE01-G112', . . . ) error in this line i am using mysql 5.7.34 version'

Comment: use and after the the turbine_name condition : turbine_name in ('SWSMHD-SC1-RWE01-G112', . . . ) and
      local_tm BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-01'

Comment: but what is the meaning of three dot in the bracket and i have uses the and after the bracket but still their is an error

Comment: dots means ur remaining comma separated turbine_names.

Comment: but that is not an optimized way to run the query i want all the records of all turbine present in the table without writing again and again

Comment: mysql doesnt support with clause or connect by clause so you have to do it hard way.